# django urls redirect me to other view

Tags: python, django, url, routes, view

I don't understand my problem here is my code:

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('blog.views',
    ...
    url(r'^(?P<slug>.+)$', 'blog', name='blog'),
    url(r'^membres$', 'membres', name='membres'),
)
```

views:

```
def blog(request, slug):
posts = Post.objects.filter(blog__slug=slug)
return render(request, 'blog/blog.html', locals())

def membres(request):
membres = User.objects.all()
return render(request, 'blog/membres.html', {'membres': membres})
```

Here is my link in my base.html template

```
<li><a href="{% url "membres" %}">List</a></li>
```

When I click the link it redirect me to the blog view and then render blog.html instead of using membres view.

I got no error in console or in my template.
All my code is in my app called 'blog'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django uses the first pattern that matches. Your first URL regex matches any string, including `/membres`, so Django never tries the second one. I suggest something like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('blog.views',
    url(r'^/blog/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', 'blog', name='blog'),
    url(r'^membres/$', 'membres', name='membres'),
)
```

If you must have a catch-all pattern, it should be the last one in the list, so the other patterns have a chance to match before:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('blog.views',
    url(r'^membres/$', 'membres', name='membres'),
    # other patterns...
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', 'blog', name='blog'),
)
```

It's also a good habit to always include the trailing slash (Django will append it to requests by default). To match a slug, I suggest `[-\w]+`, which will match any sequence of  alphanumeric characters, `_` and `-`.

Answer (score 1):

It's because urlresolver takes patterns from top to bottom and 'membres' matches `(?P<slug>.+)` so urlresolver returns `blog` view. Put more concrete urlpatterns higher. Also I suggest using more specific characters in slug regexp, i.e. `(?P<slug>[A-Za-z0-9_\-]+)`.

Answer (score 1):

Django stops at the first URL pattern that matches. This means that your
`blog` view -- which simply looks for one or more characters -- will interpret your `mysite.com/membres` URL to be a blog post with the slug `membres`.

To fix it, try swapping the order of your URL patterns:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('blog.views',
    ...
    url(r'^membres$', 'membres', name='membres'),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>.+)$', 'blog', name='blog'),
)
```

In general, you want your most general patterns at the bottom for exactly this reason.